# How to make my service run?

Tags: service, broadcast, intentfilter

I want to start a service when the power is connected to my device and show a notification but my app is doing nothing or I do not what is happenig, so please help me, I am new in the android world, maybe I miss something, mi code is the following:

My manifest:

```html
<receiver android:name="com.tlm.grhs_client.WiFiMonitor">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My Broadcast Reciever:

```html
public class WiFiMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {        
       ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
       if (info != null && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
           if (info.isConnected()) {
               //iniciar servicio
               Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ClientService.class);
               context.startService(serviceIntent);
           }
           else {
               //parar servicio
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ClientService.class);
               context.stopService(serviceIntent);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

and my service class is this:

```html
public class ClientService extends Service {

 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio fue creado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @Override
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
  // Perform your long running operations here.
  Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio iniciado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  
  Notification.Builder notiBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);
  notiBuilder.setContentTitle("Prueba");
  notiBuilder.setContentText("Esto es una prueba");
  Notification notificacion = notiBuilder.build();
  
  NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  manager.notify(1, notificacion);
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio destruido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

}
```

I turn on the wifi and establish the connection but the notification doesn't shows.

Answer (score 0):

Android notifications in this manner require a small icon, along with a title and some text as per the documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Add an icon but otherwise the code (on a quick glance) looks like it should work.

Comment: Yes, loos like it should work, but it doesn´t work, I already wrote in my code the small and large icon of the notification and still it doesn´t work.